# iOS MDM InstallMedia command not working

Tags: ios, mdm

I am working on MDM implementation for iOS. The InstallMedia command getting failed with reason "A VPP purchase record for the item could not be found."

As per my knowledge VPP is needed when we want to have paid applications. The Book which I am trying to install through MDM server is free still I am getting this error.
Here is my request plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Command</key>
    <dict>
        <key>RequestType</key>
        <string>InstallMedia</string>
        <key>MediaType</key>
        <string>Book</string>
        <key>iTunesStoreID</key>
        <integer>491636607</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>4513</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Can anyone look into this and let me know the issue and give me sample plist for Installing Books using InstallMedia?

I have gone through VPP references and I came to know that it is not supported for my country. So, what should I do to implement managed books feature using InstallMedia if I want to have paid applications and books?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a VPP license to the user for books you want to install, regardless of whether the book is paid or free.